# Deserialize Json Always Get Items null

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, system.text.json

I am deserializing a Json file, this is my Classes structures:

```
public class ControlInfoDataGroup
{
    public string UniqueId { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ControlInfoDataItem> Items { get; private set; }
    ...
} 

public class ControlInfoDataItem
{
    public string UniqueId { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ControlInfoDataItem> SubItems { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

then i deserialize my json with this codes:

```
public class JsonFileReader
{
    public ObservableCollection<ControlInfoDataGroup> Groups { get; set; }
        
    Groups = new ObservableCollection<ControlInfoDataGroup>();
    using FileStream openStream = File.OpenRead(JsonFilePath);
    var controlInfoDataGroup = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<JsonFileReader>(openStream, new JsonSerializerOptions
         {
                WriteIndented = true,
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
         });
}
```

and this is my json file content:

```
    {
      "Groups": [
        {
          "Title": "Home",
          "IsSpecialSection": false,
          "HideGroup": false,
          "IsSingleGroup": false,
          "IsExpanded": false,
          "Items": [
            {
              "Title": "Movie",
              "IsNew": false,
              "IsUpdated": false,
              "IsPreview": false,
              "HideItem": false,
              "HideNavigationViewItem": false,
              "HideSourceCodeAndRelatedControls": false,
              "IncludedInBuild": false
            }
          ],
          "InfoBadge": null
        }
      ]
    }
```

i only get "Home" and this item does not have any "Items", but according my json file, i have an item for "Home" called "Movie".
where is issue? how i can fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with public setters?

Comment: @Fildor tnx fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have strange classes, try these

```
Data controlInfoDataGroup =  await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Data>(openStream,new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        WriteIndented = true,
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    });


public class Data
{
    public ObservableCollection<ControlInfoDataGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}
public class ControlInfoDataGroup
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsSpecialSection { get; set; }
    public bool HideGroup { get; set; }
    public bool IsSingleGroup { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ControlInfoDataItem> Items { get; set; }
    public object InfoBadge { get; set; }
}

public class ControlInfoDataItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
    public bool IsUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool IsPreview { get; set; }
    public bool HideItem { get; set; }
    public bool HideNavigationViewItem { get; set; }
    public bool HideSourceCodeAndRelatedControls { get; set; }
    public bool IncludedInBuild { get; set; }
}
```